# Can api-platform return a 200 to a POST?

Tags: php, symfony, http, orm, api-platform.com

I use api-platform without ORM. This is my third API.
The 2 others are linked to a DB via Doctrine.
This one is used to link the two others, so no need of a DB.

I can't use search-filter with a GET request because I have the error:

```
Call to a member function getClassMetadata() on null
```

(because I don't map the object with an ORM...)

So I use a POST request, giving me a 201 HTTP return code.

**Can I get a 200 rather than this 201 (to satisfy the CORS...)?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In APIP you can alter any operation status by adding a key status in your POST
operation more details here https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#configuring-operations

```
#[ApiResource(
collectionOperations: [
    'post' => [
        'path' => '/grimoire',
        'status' => 301,
    ],
],
```